# Export Array into XLS? iOS Code to generate XLS?

Tags: ios, xls

Is there any possible ways to export the array values into excel sheet. Any possibilities to export the data into XLS file format.

Comment: If u find any way share with solution

Answer (score 0):

There is an open source C++ library that supports .xls file creation - this is the older binary Excel format, not the newer XML one. In addition, there is an ObjectiveC wrapper library for it, JXLS, which you can find on github at https://github.com/JanX2/JXLS.

Both the library and wrapper are quite stable and have wide usage.

Comment: The Link to download sample. The sample app, missing more files. The sample not run.

Comment: Read the README. You have to use terminal to pull other files.